# Should simple statement be surrounded by Promise.try in bluebird promises?

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, bluebird

Using promisified request module, i want to get the body attribute of the response. Not sure if I should use a Promise try.

So which one is correct here ?

**A.** Without Promise.try

```
request.getAsync("http://example.com")
       .then( x => x.body )
       .tap( x=> console.log('body:',x) )
```

**B.** With Promise.try

```
request.getAsync("http://example.com")
       .then( x => Promise.try( () => x.body ) )
       .tap( x=> console.log('body:',x) )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After the first element of a promise chain, an error is guaranteed to throw down the chain's error path and become available to be caught by a `.then(null, errorHandler)` or `.catch(errorHandler)`.

Therefore there is no point using Bluebird's `Promise.try()` other than to get a chain reliably started. Doing so will just bulk up your code and make it less efficient.

How about inner chains?

This is more interesting. Inner chains are commonly used to allow access to earlier results via closure. Flattened chains lose this ability.

Consider :

```
request.getAsync("http://example.com")
.then( x => {
    return untrusted.method().then((y) => other.method(x, y));
});
```

The inner chain has its own starter, `untrusted.method()`, which may cause failure in one of two ways:

- it may throw.
- it may return a non-thenable.

A throw is unavoidable (without addressing `untrusted.method()`), though the thrown error will be catchable in the outer chain.

But a non-thenable can be guarded against. You can write :

```
request.getAsync("http://example.com")
.then(x => {
    return Promise.try(untrusted.method).then((y) => other.method(x, y) );
});
```

Now `Promise.try()` ensures the inner chain has a reliable start. `Promise.try(untrusted.method)` is guaranteed to be thenable.

As a bonus, an error thrown by `untrusted.method()` is now catchable in the outer chain *or the inner chain*, which can be useful, particularly for error recovery.

`Promise.resolve(untrusted.method())` would similarly protect against a non-thenable being returned but would not allow a synchronous throw to be caught within the inner chain.

- **[DEMO: untrusted() throws](http://jsfiddle.net/qp710exq/2/)**
- **[DEMO: untrusted() returns value, not promise](http://jsfiddle.net/qp710exq/1/)**.

So in summary,

- within a promise chain, there's no value in wrapping synchronous expression(s) in `Promise.try()`.
- within a promise chain , there's no value in wrapping *trusted*, asynchronous function/method calls in `Promise.try()`.
- within a promise chain, there is potentially great value in wrapping an untrusted function/method call in `Promise.try()` to guarantee an inner chain's reliable start.

Comment: You seem to confuse `Promise.try` with `Promise.resolve`

Answer (score 1):

> Not sure if I should use a `Promise.try`.

**No**, you should not. In a promise `then` callback, all synchronous exceptions will be caught and lead to a rejection of the result promise, there is nothing you need to do for that. No `try`/`catch` statements, no `Promise.try` invocations. They would just be unnecessary fluff.

[`Promise.try`](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.try.html) should only be used at the start of a promise chain, where you are not yet in a promise callback.

Answer (score 0):

The [definition of this `Promise.try`](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.try.html) is:

> Start the chain of promises with `Promise.try`. Any synchronous
>   exceptions will be turned into rejections on the returned promise.

So it depends by the implementation of `request.getAsync` method. Does it throw any exception?

If the answer is "no", you do not need to use `Promise.try`.

If the answer is "yes", you **can** use `Promise.try` if you need to catch the error thrown by `request.getAsync` as rejected promise. In this case, you can wrap the 
`request.getAsync` inside `Promise.try`:

```
Promise.try(() => {
    return request.getAsync("http://example.com");
}).tap(x => console.log('body:', x.nody));
```

Please note that if the answer is "yes" but do not want to catch the exception as a rejected promise, you do not need to use `Promise.try`.

Comment: Thanks but not sure if it answers my question. If getAsync (getAsync is from bluebird-promisified request module, as I mentioned in the question) throws something, .then( x => x.body ) won't be called anyway.